# Content deserializing issues

Tags: c#, json, .net

i have following JSON. And I'm trying to deserialize it properly.

```
{
    "IDENTITY": {
        "reviewResult": {
            "reviewAnswer": "GREEN"
        },
        "country": "UKR",
        "idDocType": "ID_CARD",
        "imageIds": [
            545025840,
            1128127941
        ],
        "imageReviewResults": {
            "1128127941": {
                "reviewAnswer": "GREEN"
            },
            "545025840": {
                "reviewAnswer": "GREEN"
            }
        },
        "forbidden": false,
        "doubleSided": true,
        "stepStatuses": null
    }
}
```

So the "IDENTITY" data member could be named in different way for ex. "SELFIE" but will have same body class. Ex.

```
{
    "SELFIE": {
        "reviewResult": {
            "reviewAnswer": "GREEN"
        },
        "country": "UKR",
        "idDocType": "ID_CARD",
        "imageIds": [
            545025840,
            1128127941
        ],
        "imageReviewResults": {
            "1128127941": {
                "reviewAnswer": "GREEN"
            },
            "545025840": {
                "reviewAnswer": "GREEN"
            }
        },
        "forbidden": false,
        "doubleSided": true,
        "stepStatuses": null
    }
}
```

Same about "imageReviewResults" data member, those values is taken form "imageIds" array and can be different in each response.

How to handle it properly? like Dictionary<string, Object>?

```
[JsonPropertyOrder(1)]
        public Dictionary<string, IdentityData> Identity { get; set; }

[DataContract]
public class IdentityData
{
    [JsonPropertyName("reviewResult")]
    [DataMember(Name = "reviewResult")]
    public ReviewResultData ReviewResult { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("country")]
    [DataMember(Name = "country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("idDocType")]
    [DataMember(Name = "idDocType")]
    public string DocType { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("imageIds")]
    [DataMember(Name = "imageIds")]
    public int[] ImageIds { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: _"like Dictionary<string, Object>?"_ - yes, but instead of `object` using a class you generate to hold the JSON data. Recursively, so also for `imageReviewResults`. See https://json2csharp.com/.

Comment: Yes, i did like that Dictionary<string, ImageReviewResults> for both such cases. But still it cannot be serialized and just return null. Without errors or anything. Just null on result. Also tried your https://json2csharp.com/ but its generating a class without Dictionary<string, "Some Object"> obviously. I did smth like that [JsonPropertyOrder(1)]
        public Dictionary<string, IdentityData> Identity { get; set; }
still getting not serialized object

Comment: Please [edit] to show your code.

Comment: Edited post with code.

Comment: How do you deserialize the JSON?

Answer (score -1):

you have to parse your json in order to get a root value

```
var rootProperty= JsonDocument.Parse(json).RootElement.EnumerateObject().First();

string rootPropertyName= rootProperty.Name;

IdentityData identityData = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer
                                 .Deserialize<IdentityData>(rootProperty.Value);
```

or some people love the dictionaries

```
var dict= System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer
                .Deserialize<Dictionary<string,IdentityData>>(json).First();

string rootPropertyName=dict.Key;
IdentityData identityData=dict.Value;
```

classes

```
[DataContract]
public class ReviewResult
{
    [JsonPropertyName("reviewAnswer")]
    [DataMember(Name = "reviewAnswer")]
    public string ReviewAnswer { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class IdentityData
{
    [JsonPropertyName("reviewResult")]
    public ReviewResult ReviewResult { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("imageReviewResults")]
    public Dictionary<string, ReviewResult> ImageReviewResults { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("country")]
    [DataMember(Name = "country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("idDocType")]
    [DataMember(Name = "idDocType")]
    public string DocType { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("imageIds")]
    [DataMember(Name = "imageIds")]
    public int[] ImageIds { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, IdentityData>>(json)` instead of `....RootElement.EnumerateObject().First()`?

Comment: @CodeCaster What is the difference? I dont like any dictionaries, prefer typed objects. And my code makes a clear access to  name and value

Comment: You can replace your three lines with the first inline code fragment from my answer. They're also using Newtonsoft.

Comment: @CodeCaster I see JsonPropertyName so I dont think that it is Newtonsoft;

Comment: No, thats not Newtonsoft. Newtonsoft is a bit smarter, but i don't use it anymore.